# How to count the numer of rows containing a string in a multiline list?

Tags: python, list

I'm a newbie of python...

I have created a list like a table with rows and 4 columns

```
70782763 Pilot 17,54 4,9

74006423 Pilot 19,95 4,9

74924394 Pilot 16,06 4,9

70782763 Auto 20,9 6,5

70706423 Track 19,1 5,9

74924394 Track 19,4 5,9
```

how can I count how many rows contain in the second column [1] the word "Pilot"?

the normal

```
table.count('Pilot') or table[1].count('Pilot')
```

returns me wrong values

and, eventually, how can I delete all the rows that have in the second column a value found less then 3 times?

Thanks

Comment: The format of your table is unclear. Is it a list of lists-of-strings, or just a list of strings with commas separating items in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly:

```
table = [[70782763, 'Pilot', 54, 9],
         [74006423, 'Pilot', 14, 9],
         [74924394, 'Pilot', 4, 9],
         [70782763, 'Auto', 9, 5],
         [70706423, 'Track', 15, 9],
         [74924394, 'Track', 45, 9]]

print(sum([x[1] == 'Pilot' for x in table]))
```

for the second part of your request, if I understood correctly you wanted that the rows that have a string in the second column that repeats no more twice will be removed.

```
num_of_shows = {}
for row in table:
    if row[1] in num_of_shows.keys():
        num_of_shows[row[1]] += 1
    else:
        num_of_shows[row[1]] = 1
table = [x for x in table if num_of_shows[x[1]] >= 3]
```

Comment: Thank you, Aking. I've tried to give you a vote, but my reputation doesn't permit me. Sorry. Very simple and very elegant. Do you know also an elegant way to delete all the rows that have in the second column a value found less then 3 times? Thanks again

Comment: what do you mean less than 3 times? like in your example the last 3 because 'Auto' is only once and 'Track' because it is only twice?

Comment: Thanks Aking.
it works. :-)
I don't understand how, but it works.
I'll study your few line with extreme interest. Thanks again.
that apparently simple lines of python that works on the entire list are very powerful but not so easy for me...

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

possibly

```
pilotCount = 0
for x in y:
    if "Pilot" in x:
        pilotCount = pilotCount +1
        list.pop(list.index(x))
print(f"Pilot appears {pilotCount} times in the list.")
```

Comment: @Aking's print works better and is less typing, just make sure you pop the index to remove it.